# Rails console return list of model if model's method returns false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to find all vehicles that are not automatic. In my Vehicle model I have a method auto which return true for automatic and false for manual. In the rails console how do I return a list of all vehicles that are manual? Below does not work:

```
vehicles = Vehicle.find(:all);

manual_vehicles = vehicles.Where(auto.present? != true);
```

models/vehicle.rb

```
def auto
  Auto.where(:vehicle_id=>self.id)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my Vehicle model I have a method auto which return true for
>   automatic and false for manual.

This is false, your following method returns an ActiveRecord::Relation containing all the Auto where the attribute `vehicle_id` is equal to the Vehicle `id`:

```
def auto
  Auto.where(:vehicle_id=>self.id)
end
```

If you want a piece of code that will test if a Vehicle has an Auto associated with it, use this:

```
def auto?
  Auto.where(vehicle_id: self.id).present? # returns TRUE or FALSE
end
```

Then If you want to **get all** the **vehicles** that are **manual**:

```
Vehicle.all.select{|vehicle| vehicle.auto? != true }
```

Or at the DB-level (faster, better, stronger!):

```
Vehicle.where('id NOT IN (?)', Auto.pluck(:vehicle_id).uniq.compact)
# This will get all vehicles where there id is not contained in the Auto table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Vehicle.all.select(&:auto?)
```

Note that this is slow if there are a large number of vehicles, since they will all be loaded into ruby. It's more efficient therefore to do the test in SQL. E.g. if your `#auto?` method merely looks at an `auto` boolean field you could do this instead:

```
Vehicle.where(auto: true)
```

That also has the advantage of getting the result as a `Relation` rather than an `Array`, which allows you further refine the statement downstream before calling the database.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `auto?' for #<Vehicle:0xf5f488>

Comment: you have to define an `auto?` method in your model, but please consider @Mori comment about loading all instances in your memory.